# Symfony 4 - grouping categories

Tags: symfony, grouping, categories, symfony4

I have table for category and parent_category with ralation ManyToOne.
This is my 'category' table:
[image]

And this is my 'parent_category' table:

[image]

This is my code in FormType:

```
->add('category',EntityType::class,array(
                'class'=>Category::class,
                'choice_label'=>'name',
                'group_by'=>'parent_id'

            ))
```

And this is the answer in browser.

[image]

My parent category must be for 1-Якета (Jackets) ,2-Блузи (Blouses),3->Панталони (Pants).I want the string value of this parent_id,like this:

```
Якета
--Пролетни
--Зимни
--Жилетки
Блузи
--Тениски
--Ризи
--Дълъг ръкав
Панталони
--Къси
--Дълги
--Дънки
```

How to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
'group_by' => function($value, $key, $index) {
       return $value->getParent()->getName();
    }
```

Comment: How to do it the right way to solve my problem?Thanks

Comment: if your Category entity has getParent() method  that returns ParentCategory entity and ParentCategory entity has getName() method then it should work.

Comment: Thank you i made query and all is okay now!

Comment: Why did you create that method in your CategoryRepository? You do not need that for the grouping. The method getParent() shoud be in your Entity class not in Repository.

Comment: Yes,my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

New updated code in **FormType**:

```
'group_by' => function(Category $category) {
                    return $category->getParent()->getName();

                }
```